# How do I create a file within "docker run"

Tags: docker

How do I create a file on the containers file system so that

```
docker run some-image some-command > somefile
```

seems somehow easy enough, only that `somefile` is always created on the host's filesystem and not within the container.

I also tried:

```
docker run some-image (some-command > somefile)
docker run some-image "some-command > somefile"
docker run some-image "(some-command > somefile)"
```

Without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
docker run some-image bash -c "some-command > somefile"
```

Note, however, that your container will stop once `some-command` finishes executing. The file will be written, but the container will have stopped. `some-image` will not be affected either, so running another container based on `some-image` will not have `somefile`.

Assuming that's the behavior you want, the above will work.